# Is it possible to practice AJAX using the Brackets web editor with local files only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

What I'm ultimately trying to accomplish: Making a site that allows you to browse through videos and add/remove them from an AJAX-controlled playlist. So far, my website has only been created through Brackets using local web files, and I'm curious how much I'll need to change my work environment if I want to begin using AJAX with my website. I've never used AJAX before, if that isn't obvious....

Comment: Ajax is pretty straight forward to use and you'll only need to include jQuery to do so. However, you will need some sort of server-side code like like a `php` script for the Ajax to be useful.  THe Ajax will make a call to the sever script which will process the request then optionally, return some data to the Ajax callback. Check out [these demos](http://www.sitepoint.com/demos/ajax/)

Comment: You really need to how http works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a local server like WAMP (http://www.wampserver.com/en/), MAMP(https://www.mamp.info/en/), or LAMP

Comment: Thanks! In case anyone needs additional help in the future: I downloaded XAMPP, ran Apache, moved my project folder into C:\xampp\htdocs then opened it in Brackets from there. =) Wish me luck in further website building!